# Powershell Graph API SDK Update statements

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I`m exploring msgraph-sdk-powershell module to execute some automations against Azure AD. I have trouble creating hash table for Update-MgAdministrativeUnit cmdlet. I want to update the members of a Administrative Unit (add and remove members) but the help dose not provide adequate information how to define the hash table:

```
 MEMBERS <IMicrosoftGraphDirectoryObject[]>: Users and groups that are members of this Adminsitrative Unit.
    HTTP Methods: GET (list members), POST (add members), DELETE (remove members).
      [Id <String>]: Read-only.
      [DeletedDateTime <DateTime?>]:
```

Dose anyone have experience with this command ?

Regards,
Ognyan

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and the errors you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding or removing members is currently not supported.